# Wanting to install ati driver for duel graphics AMD8 with radeon 6470

Tags: ati

With 11.10 I used to download the latest ati driver for my duel graphics Radeon card problem.
With 12.04 the graphics problem is resolved it seems.
But the Ubuntu driver on  my Laptop is burning.
So I wanted to install the ati driver to see if it would be better.
In the old days when the laptop would not run without the ati driver I simply ran recovery mode and it promoted me for my user and password.
Installing 12.04 I changed my user to user1.
But now in 12.04 it doesnt stop at the prompt for name and password but takes me to a window where I can drop to root etc.
Can someone tell me how to input the command I tried terminal but it doesnt recognise my command cd /home/user1/Downloads
Should I do it in recovery using root 
If so what are the commands please
Or better still tell me the fix to keep my graphics cool if I keep ubuntu driver. Or what you recommend?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have now solved this I think
I downloaded via Additional Hardware Drivers applet it gave ne error in install but the temperature has dropped significantly from 62 to 44 dont ask me why..Evidently some of the install went ok anyway... 
I also now tweaked   Cataylst.